# How to filter tasks for previous calendar month

Tags: calculated-column-formula

How to setup view, that would show all "Tasks" for previous month ?
I can find first and last day of previous month.

End of previous month:

```
End_of_previous   =DATE(YEAR([Activity Date]),MONTH([Activity Date]),1)-1
```

Start of previous month:

```
Start_of_previous    =DATE(YEAR([Activity Date]),MONTH([Activity Date])-1,1)
```

But how to setup view that it would show dates in this range?

Comment: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2015/03/sharepoint-create-view-for-only-last.html?m=1 Please check above link your query will be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found answer. It is explained [here](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/)